# Complex SQL Join with 5 tables

Tags: sql, join, create-table

I'm working on a relatively huge application, which contains quite a lot of tables. I have to write a SQL query which involve, after simplification, 5 tables (see the jpg for the joins).

The idea is as follows:
Persons have addresses, and addresses have a type (private, pro, etc) and a country.
Persons can also have options. These options (illustrated here in the option table with a name_id) can be linked to an address type.

The idea is to extract all the persons who have one or more addresses which are specified by a country AND by the fact that they also appear in the [option address] table.

For example, let's say we want the persons who have an address with country_id=1. The resultset must exclude the persons who don't have the same address type linked to their options.

Well... I'm not sure I understand myself :)

But anyway, here's the SQL to create all the stuff.

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `apt` (`person_id`,`type_id`),
  KEY `apid` (`person_id`),
  KEY `atid` (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `address` (`person_id`, `type_id`, `country_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 1, 1),
(3, 2, 2),
(5, 1, 2),
(6, 2, 1),
(7, 1, 1),
(7, 2, 2),
(8, 1, 1),
(9, 2, 1);

CREATE TABLE `address_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `tid` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `address_type` (`id`) VALUES
(1),
(2);

CREATE TABLE `option` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `oid` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `onp` (`name_id`,`person_id`),
  KEY `opid` (`person_id`),
  KEY `on` (`name_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `option` (`id`, `name_id`, `person_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 5),
(5, 1, 6),
(6, 1, 7),
(7, 1, 8),
(8, 1, 9);

CREATE TABLE `option_address_type` (
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ot` (`option_id`,`type_id`),
  KEY `ooid` (`option_id`),
  KEY `otid` (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `option_address_type` (`option_id`, `type_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 1),
(3, 2),
(4, 2),
(5, 1),
(6, 1),
(7, 1),
(7, 2),
(8, 1),
(8, 2);

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `pid` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `person` (`id`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9);


ALTER TABLE `address`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `address_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `address_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `address_type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `option`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `option_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `option_address_type`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `option_address_type_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `option` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `option_address_type_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `address_type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: +1 for creation of the table script, with data inserted so people can play around with it. Good stuff

Comment: What are your desired results if country = 1 -- which people should return?

Comment: Always nice to have a table creation script (especially the FK references).  Personally would have preferred 'non-key' columns, just for examples.  mySQL for RDBMS?  ...I think your database schema is awkwardly put together, though.  Among other things, does the existence of an `address` record imply the existence of an address-option (could that table be removed)?  What is `option.name_id` referring to?  What does `option_address_type.type_id` refer to?

Comment: name_id is a link to an other table, that I didn't describe here. And no, a person can have only an address without option. But a person can have an option, which can be linked to an address type.

Comment: Well, as Clockwork-Muse said, the schema is a bit awkwardly. I'm now trying to rethink the whole thing, even if it means to re-code a big part of the application. But thanks for your help! And if, finally, this current version is still the best, I will for sure re-open the question, if I didn't find how to write this sql! Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
select person_id
from   address adr
,      `option` opt
,      option_address_type opt_adt
where  adr.country_id = 1
and    opt.person_id = adr.person_id
and    opt_adt.option_id = opt.option_id
and    opt_adt.type_id = adr.type_id
```

or

```
select person_id
from   address adr
inner join   `option` opt
  on     opt.person_id = adr.person_id
  and    adr.country_id = 1
inner join    option_address_type opt_adt
  on      opt_adt.option_id = opt.option_id
  and    opt_adt.type_id = adr.type_id
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this working with MySQL? Because I have a syntax error on the FROM clause. Seems that comma-separated tablesaren't supported...

Comment: Option needs to be wrapped in single quotes since it's a reserved word in MySQL...

Comment: I have added the SQL 92 syntax as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand what your desired results are.  When the country is 1, exclude the people where address type not equal to option address type?

Something like this?

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Person p
    JOIN address a ON p.Id = a.Person_ID
    JOIN address_type at ON a.Type_ID = at.Id
    JOIN `option` o ON p.Id = o.person_Id
    JOIN option_address_type oat ON o.id = oat.option_id
WHERE a.country_id = 1 AND at.id <> oat.type_id;
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e8ad/13).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I have to leave now, but I will try your sql tomorrow and explain better the expected result if needed.